# Telling Python to save a .txt file to a certain directory on Windows and Mac

Tags: python

How do you tell Python where to save a text file?

For example, my computer is running the Python file off my desktop. I want it to save all the text file in my documents folder, not on my desktop. How do I do that in a script like this?

```
name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = name_of_file + ".txt"
#Alter this line in any shape or form it is up to you.
file1 = open(completeName , "w")

toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")

file1.write(toFile)

file1.close()
```

Answer (score 101):

Just use an absolute path when opening the filehandle for writing.

```
import os.path

save_path = 'C:/example/'

name_of_file = raw_input("What is the name of the file: ")

completeName = os.path.join(save_path, name_of_file+".txt")         

file1 = open(completeName, "w")

toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")

file1.write(toFile)

file1.close()
```

You could optionally combine this with `os.path.abspath()` as described in Bryan's answer to automatically get the path of a user's Documents folder. Cheers!

Answer (score 46):

Use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to combine the path to the `Documents` directory with the `completeName` (filename?) supplied by the user.

```
import os
with open(os.path.join('/path/to/Documents',completeName), "w") as file1:
    toFile = raw_input("Write what you want into the field")
    file1.write(toFile)
```

If you want the `Documents` directory to be relative to the user's home directory, you could use something like:

```
os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Documents',completeName)
```

---

Others have proposed using `os.path.abspath`. Note that `os.path.abspath` does not resolve `'~'` to the user's home directory:

```
In [10]: cd /tmp
/tmp

In [11]: os.path.abspath("~")
Out[11]: '/tmp/~'
```

Answer (score 16):

A small update to this. `raw_input()` is renamed as `input()` in Python 3.

[Python 3 release note](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)

Answer (score 13):

Another simple way without using import OS is,

```
outFileName="F:\\folder\\folder\\filename.txt"
outFile=open(outFileName, "w")
outFile.write("""Hello my name is ABCD""")
outFile.close()
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to save a file to a particular DIRECTORY and FILENAME here is some simple example.  It also checks to see if the directory has or has not been created.

```
import os.path
directory = './html/'
filename = "file.html"
file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
if not os.path.isdir(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
file = open(file_path, "w")
file.write(html)
file.close()
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 4):

Using an absolute or relative string as the filename.

```
name_of_file = input("What is the name of the file: ")
completeName = '/home/user/Documents'+ name_of_file + ".txt"
file1 = open(completeName , "w")
toFile = input("Write what you want into the field")
file1.write(toFile)
file1.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You probably could have just shown the line of code where you assign the file path to completeName, just to make your change/solution a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Just give your desired path if file does not exist earlier;

```
        from os.path import abspath
        with open ('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\results.txt', mode = 'w') as final1:
            print(final1.write('This is my new file.'))

        print(f'Text has been processed and saved at {abspath(final1.name)}')
```

Output will be:

```
Text has been processed and saved at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want save file or another some in folder you can use `shutil` module from base python library.

```
import shutil

path_to_file = f'home/user/My_Project/media/{my_file_name}'
path_to_folder = 'home/user/my_folder/'
   
shutil.copy(path_to_file, path_to_folder)
```

You can do it ever for some file's list or in Django querysets:

```
from images.models import Image
import shutil

images = Image.objects.all()
for image in images:
    image_path = image.file.path
    shutil.copy(image_path, path_to folder)
```

All your choised files will put in directed folder.