# How to save a file with python in different location?

Tags: python

I am creating a file with the help of python programming language in my hard drive. The code I am using is:

```
file = open('test.txt','w')

file.write('Blah Blah')

file.close()
```

This code creates `test.txt` file in hard drive but the file is saved in the default location of project. I want to save the file in other location like desktop or somewhere else. Can anyone tell me how to do this.

I am using python 3.5

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: did you try googling ?
possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024248/telling-python-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-certain-directory-on-windows-and-mac

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass a full absolute or relative path when opening the file:

```
file = open('/My/Example/Desktop/test.txt','w')
```

Answer (score 9):

Just specify the location in a string variable and then added to the name of file you want to create with doing `open`:

```
import os
my_dir = 'C:\\Test\\My_Dir'
file_name = 'test.txt'
fname = os.path.join(my_dir, file_name)
file = open(fname,'w')
```

Comment: _Please_ don't build file paths by string concatenation. It is very easy to get wrong, as you have here (you probably don't really want `C:\\Test\\My_Dirtest.txt`). [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) exists for a reason.

Comment: @Chris...Yea...totally missed it...Thanks for the head's up