# How to get time from Properties

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python script:

```
import ftplib
import hashlib
import httplib
import pytz
import datetime
import urllib
import os
import glob

def ftphttp():
 localtime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc).isoformat()
 cam = "002"
 lscam = localtime + cam
 ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost','kevin403','S$ip1234')
 ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

 m=hashlib.md5()
 m.update(lscam)
 dd=m.hexdigest()

 for image in glob.glob(os.path.join('Desktop/images/*.png')):
  with open(image, 'rb') as file:
   ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd+ '.png', file)

 x = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost', 8086)
 x.connect()
 f = {'ts' : localtime}
 x.request('GET','/camera/store?cam='+cam+'&'+urllib.urlencode(f)+'&fn='+dd)
 y = x.getresponse()
 z=y.read()
 x.close()
 ftp.quit()
```

I wanted to get the time from the file properties because i do not want it from the time that i send. Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/237079

Comment: Its a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: Hi @Sumit can getmtime use as a ISOdatetime format?

Comment: @Sumit you free to help me?

Comment: @Sumit can help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943625/how-to-use-getmtime-for-multiple-files?noredirect=1#comment65242252_38943625

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alvin, You cannot get **ISOdatetime** from *getmtime* directly, if you want to convert the output date from *getmtime*, you can do it in following manner:

```
import os.path, time
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

ts = os.path.getmtime(file_path) 
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, pytz.utc)

timeZone= timezone('supported_timezone')
#converting the timestamp in ISOdatetime format
dt.astimezone(timeZone).isoformat()
```

Output e.g.: '2016-02-16T23:32:06.260088-05:00' for 'US/Eastern' timezone

Comment: But i wanted this isodatetime format: 2016-02-16T23:32:06.260088Z

Comment: Can you let me know that in '260088Z' what you are trying to refer by **'Z'**?

Comment: Because my web service Isodatetime require to have the 'Z' in order to store into the database

Comment: Thanks it works, i just encode the isodatetime for the output then can store already.

Comment: But do you know how to store different file with their own timestamp with getmtime?

Comment: instead of one file like this : ts = os.path.getmtime('Desktop/images/test0.png'). because i got multiple file that consist of test0.png - test3.png

Comment: @AlvinWee I didn't got your scenario, but if you want to store file with file timestamp, you can create a new file with timestamp name and with any extension then write to the file and store(for reference you can check following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024248/telling-python-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-certain-directory-on-windows-and-mac).

Comment: As right now this line of code is only get one file timestamp:  ts = os.path.getmtime('Desktop/images/test0.png'). But what if i send multiple file from a folder and get all the file timestamp. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @AlvinWee, if you have multiple files, you can store all the files from the folder to python list and using python for loop you can loop through each file and get the *os.path.getmtime()* for each of the respective file, then you can write the logic of storing the filename with the timestamp naming pattern.

Comment: can you help me with this? Trying to do this too.