# Capture and save running process

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to capture "print('Recording GPS Position...')"  on the SD card. For now, this is printing on terminal directly I want to capture this runtime process (p_1) from terminal and store on the SD card as it is being executed. How do I do this?

Also in general what is a way to capture and store processes at runtime from terminal and store on the SD card (note I do want to store processes as it is being executed and not after its execution is done).

```
import sys
import os
import time
import subprocess, shlex
import signal
import serial
import psutil
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def recording():
    flag = 0
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 921600, timeout=1)
    ser.flushOutput()

    # ROSBAG Recordings (Shell commands that execute the messages on the terminal)

    messages = 'rosbag record -o GPS_Position.bag dji_sdk/gps_position', 'rosbag record -o IMU_Data.bag dji_sdk/imu', 'rosbag record -o Attitude.bag dji_sdk/attitude', 'rosbag record -o Velodyne_Packets.bag velodyne_packets', 'rosbag record -o Velodyne_Points.bag velodyne_points',  # rosbag record -o Velocity.bag dji_sdk/velocity'

    while flag == 0:
        try:
            args1 = shlex.split(messages[0])  # messages[0] = rosbag record -o GPS_Position.bag dji_sdk/gps_position
            #print (args1)
            p_1 = subprocess.Popen(args1, stdout=PIPE)
            print('Recording GPS Position...')
            p_1.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to choose a directory for your SD card, and instead of `print()`ing to the terminal you'll `write()` to the file you choose.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Edit: it's been answered better here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8024254/8240691 but it would still be worth your while to look over the input/output documentation.

Comment: Thank you I could get it working for text format please see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079458/redirecting-ros-bag-file-to-external-storage-using-python. I am trying to change from txt format to bag format