# How to create a file in a different directory? (python)

Tags: python, file

I am currently stuck with the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/V1.9/Storage/Logs/Date_2018-08-02_12:51.txt'
```

My code to open the file is the following:

```
nameDir = os.path.join('/home/pi/V1.9/Storage/Logs', "Date_" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M") + ".txt")
f = open(nameDir, 'a')
```

I am trying to save a file to a certain path, which is /home/pi/V1.9/Storage/Logs. I am not sure why it can't find it, since I have already created the folder Logs in that space. The only thing being created is the text file. I am not sure if its suppose to join up like that, but I generally tried to follow the stages on this thread: [Telling Python to save a .txt file to a certain directory on Windows and Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024248/telling-python-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-certain-directory-on-windows-and-mac)

Comment: `open(nameDir, 'w')`

Comment: @Rakesh should it matter? It says that append will also create the file, if the file is not there.

Comment: @Lukali: The docs says `a` is for appending (https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html). What source are you refering to by 'It says'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open() in Python does not create a file if it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967194/open-in-python-does-not-create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Yes, opening the file in `'a'`  mode should create it if it doesn't exist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23566951/4014959

Comment: I can't use 'w' because I am planning to open the file more than once. I need to create a file with a certain date, and then output the whole log from that date to the file. Also I have now tried a+. I am actually getting the same error?

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to put ':' in file names. It's ok on *nix systems, but if you want to send that file to a Windows system, or even just write it to a Windows filesystem (NTFS or one of the FAT variants, which are still commonly used on USB sticks) on your own machine, it will cause problems.

Comment: @PM2Ring you're right. Ive noticed it a bit ago and have already made the change, so it doesn't seem to be that. I changed it to '_'

Comment: As I said, using `'a'` mode isn't the cause of your problem, despite what the answers below claim. Are you _certain_ that the directory does actually exist?

Comment: Yes Lukali, `a` should work and create the file if it doesn't exist, just check the path is right
try this in the terminal `touch /home/pi/V1.9/Storage/Logs/Date_2018-08-02_12:51.txt` and tell me the output

Comment: @HossamAhmedAl-Dokkani Very weird situation. I actually do the following in command line: git clone https://github.com/Ritzerk/V1.9.git and then touch /home/pi/V1.9/Storage/Logs just to get not a directory error. If you do look on the github, the folder is present there.

Comment: tell me the output of `echo $PWD` where you run `git clone` command

Comment: @HossamAhmedAl-Dokkani I get no message when I do touch /home/pi/V1.9/storage/Logs and touch /home/pi/V1.9/Storage . It's odd. I will try changing the capital on the storage it might make all the difference just like it did in the command prompt.

Comment: @Lukali there problem here is dir tree when you run 'touch /home/pi/V1.9/storage/Logs` you create a file(not a dir) named 'Logs'
just run `echo $PWD` where you do git clone and tell me the output

Comment: @HossamAhmedAl-Dokkani Thank you hossam I am no longer getting the error. I had to change /home/pi/V1.9/Storage/Logs/Date... to /home/pi/V1.9/storage/Logs/Date... . Anyway to make you the answer to this post?

Comment: @Lukali you are welcome, I delete my answer since it was irrelevant. so no worries glad that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the file use the write mode `w` or use `a+`

```
f = open(nameDir, 'w')
f = open(nameDir, 'a+')
```

Use only `a` append if the file already exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
f = open(nameDir, 'a')
```

'a' stands for *append*, which means: the file should already exist, you get an error message because it doesn't. Use 'w' (*write*) instead, Python will create the file in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but similar error. I had:

```py
with open("/Users//jacobivanov/Desktop/NITL/Data Analysis/Completed Regressions/{0} Temperature Regression Parameters.txt".format(data_filename), mode = 'w+') as output:
```

Because data_filename was in reality a global file path, it concatenated and looked for a non-existent directory. If you are getting this error and are referring to the file path of an external file in the name of the generated file, check to verify it isn't doing this.

Might help someone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33099657)