# how to write csv file into specific folder

Tags: python, csv, directory

i am trying to write several .csv file into one specific directory

here is my code

```
with open(f+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    writer.writerow(["index", "B", "G", "R"])

    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)

    writer.writerow(["Mean", mean_b/total_b, mean_g/total_g, mean_r/total_r])
    writer.writerow("STD", np.sqrt(var_b/total_b), np.sqrt(var_g/total_g), np.sqrt(var_r/total_r))
```

i have created the csv file into the directory which is same as the .py file
however i would like to create a directory and create my csv file in it

i know i need to us os.makedirs() function

but i don't know whether i have to create the directory first and designate the path for the csv file or i simply put the directory name into the open() function

please help me

Comment: Please post your code as **text**, not as an image.

Comment: Before you start looping over the files make sure if the folder exists. If its not - create it. You can use 'os.path.isdir("/the_folder_name")'

Comment: I took the liberty of swapping your image for actual text/code. I hope I got all the nuances and spelling correctly. Correct the block if something is out of place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telling Python to save a .txt file to a certain directory on Windows and Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024248/telling-python-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-certain-directory-on-windows-and-mac)

Comment: thanks for the correcting, i am new to python and english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply create the directory and except directory exists error

```
try:
   os.mkdir("./CSV")
except OSError as e:
   print("Directory exists")

with open("./CSV/" + f + ".csv", newline="") as csvfile:
   [...]
```

Comment: oh, i change "" to '' and it works  although i don't know the reason.
thanks for solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using os I recommend using the pathlib module.
You can create a directory with:

```
path = Path('path/to/dir')
path.mkdir(parents=True)
```

to create the directory and all its missing parent dirs.
After doing this you can create a file in the new directory with

```
fpath = (path / 'filename').with_suffix('.csv')
with fpath.open(mode='w+') as csvfile:
    # your csv writer code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check for the directory like this just before `open` statement

```
dir_path = 'folder_to_save_csv_file_in'
if not os.path.isdir(dir_path):
    os.makedirs(dir_path)

with open('{file_path}.csv'.format(file_path=os.path.join(dir_path, file_name), 'w+') as csv_file:
    ....
```